# Tkinter unable to alloc 71867 bytes

Tags: python, tkinter

so, I am playing with GUI and with Tkinter, I was trying to make a notepad in python.

my code so far:

```
from Tkinter import *
def hello():
    print "hello!"

ventana = Tk()

barra_menu=Menu(ventana)
barra_menu.add_command(label="Archivos")
barra_menu.add_cascade(label="Guardar", menu =barra_menu)

ventana.config(menu=barra_menu)

notepad =Text()
notepad.pack()
ventana.mainloop()
```

and when I run the script this error shows up:

```
unable to alloc 71867 bytes

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Comment: I reckon `barra_menu.add_cascade(label="Guardar", menu =barra_menu)` is causing an infinite loop! You are adding `barra_menu` to itself.

Comment: thank you, I delete that, and now it's working. I'm learning and I don't know sources to read about tkinter, anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve but it looks like this line

```
barra_menu.add_cascade(label="Guardar", menu =barra_menu)
```

is creating an infinite loop, as it is using itself as a parameter. The loop presumably ends when your system runs out of memory and hence the error.

An immediate fix is to remove the `menu` parameter. If you want a menu attached to that button use a different menu.